# Cómo documentar atributos de un componente personalizado (JSF 2.2)

Tags: java, jsf, java-ee

A partir de `JSF 2.2` no hay necesidad de crear un documento `TLD` sino que hay unos nuevos atributos añadidos a `@FacesComponent( createTag,namespace,value,tagName)` por lo que ya no es necesario el `TLD`.

Pero ahora cómo se le agrega documentación a los atributos del componente creado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desafortunadamente, aún se requiere el archivo XML (por ejemplo, `mis-componentes.taglib.xml`) para agregar documentación a un componente personalizado.

Como menciona [Arjan Tijms](http://arjan-tijms.omnifaces.org/) es este [*issue*](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC-1193) abierto en el [Java.net JIRA](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES_SPEC_PUBLIC/) —marcado como crítico, por cierto—, si el autor de un componente desea declarar los atributos del componente (para documentación, herramientas), XML todavía tiene que ser utilizado.

Aunque en ese *issue* se menciona que añadir esta característica se ha *planeado* para JSF 2.3, aún no aparece en los borradores del [JSR correspondiente](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=372).

Comment: Ya que también estas en StackOverflow (english) acá dejo el link de mi pregunta la cual tiene algo adicional a ver si me puedes ayudar, muchas gracias !             http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34603945/how-to-add-tag-documentation-to-attributes-of-facescomponentcreatetag